# Setup for React Native/TypeScript/Testing Library/Jest not working

Tags: typescript, react-native, jestjs, babeljs, react-native-testing-library

I'm trying to setup a React Native/TypeScript application to be tested with Jest and `@testing-library/react-native`;

So far I'm getting this error:

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
```

Previously I faced a `Missing class properties transform` error, so I added `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties` to the Babel config already included in the original bootstrapping with `expo init`, but once I do that I get this other error, and nothing I've tried so far works.

This is my babel config:

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: [
      "babel-preset-expo",
      ["@babel/preset-env", { targets: { node: "current" } }],
      "@babel/preset-typescript"
    ],
    plugins: ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]
  };
};
```

and my Jest configuration:

```
"jest": {
   "preset": "react-native"
}
```

The breaking test:

```
import React from "react";
import App from "../App";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react-native";

describe("App", () => {
  it("renders", () => {
    const { container: received } = render(<App />);

    expect(received).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Please note that I've spent some time trying different combinations of presets/plugins/configs so this may not be the ideal setup. I'm trying to understand if there is an actual limitation of this specific stack that I've chosen (so far I couldn't find a precise up to date example using this exact stack), a misconfiguration, or an actual bug that I should raise. I also don't know to which package the bug --if any-- actually belongs, should I report it to Jest? Or React Native? or Babel? Or Testing Library?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: did you ever get this figured out? Can you post the answer to help others?

Comment: @rap Unfortunately I didn't, I couldn't make the project work with the desired stack. I ended up choosing a different stack.